# Building NHibernate query throws - variable 'x' of type referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I am building a query to return Components that match filter values, but when I tried adding a new filter ran into

> variable 'c' of type 'Component' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

I've been building up the query slowly and have the following working as I want

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString, string typeFilter)
{

  Supplier supplierAlias = null;
  var query = Session.QueryOver<Component>()
                   .JoinAlias(x => x.Supplier, ()=> supplierAlias);

  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
      query = query.WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Name)
                 .IsInsensitiveLike(String.Format("%{0}%", searchString));

  switch (sortOrder)
  {
      case "Component desc":
          query = query.OrderBy(c => c.Name).Desc;
          break;
      case "Type":
          query = query.OrderBy(c=>c.ComponentType).Asc;
          break;
      case "Type desc":
          query = query.OrderBy(c=>c.ComponentType).Desc;
          break;
      default:
          query = query.OrderBy(c => c.Name).Asc;
          break;
  }

  var result = query.List();
  return View(result);
}
```

But now I want to add into this the option for the user to select a `Type` to filter to in just the same way as the `searchString` is currently conditionally used to add a Where. If the `typeFilter` is given then add another where, but when I try that I get the exception thrown.

I have tried with a `Where`, `WhereRestrictionOn` and `And` - I've also tried moving the `typeFilter` block above the `searchString` block but they all give the same result - which is the exception.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typeFilter))
    query = query.And(c=>c.ComponentType.ToString() == typeFilter);
```

the `ComponentType` is an enum that I want to allow the user to filter on.

**Edit (the answer)**
OK the answer was to use `Enum.Parse` as Rob G said; it is a bit 'fiddly' so I'm posting the **code that works** here because it's easier to read here than in a comment.

```
query = query.Where(c=> c.ComponentType == (Component.ComponentCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(Component.ComponentCode), typeFilter));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Enum.TryParse

```
TheEnum enumType;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typeFilter))
     query = query.And(c => Enum.TryParse<TheEnum>(typeFilter, out enumType) && enumType== c.ComponentType)
```

Comment: That doesn't compile, but I tried to restructure it but ended up with the same error about the variable not being defined. `if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(typeFilter))
                query = query.Where(c => (Enum.Parse(typeof(ComponentIndexViewModel.ComponentCode), c.ComponentType.ToString())).ToString() == typeFilter);`

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in and see what ComponentType is at that point?

Comment: The value in `typeFilter` is a valid string representation of an enum, but the debugger doesn't break down the expression to determine what the `c.ComponentType` is.